# Write to a dynamic Column in EF Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I currently have many if statement when saving data to my database because the Column changes dynamically. My code would be far more efficient if I could use the "name" string to dynamically change the column that I need to save too.

```
        if (String.Compare(name, "MWSAccessKeyID", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0) 
        {               
                var DBobj = db.AccountsConfigDatas.Find(0);
                DBobj.MWSAccessKeyID = NewValue;
                db.Entry(DBobj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();               
        }
```

**What I have tried:**
I have researched this topic for a couple of hours. I believe I'm using the wrong search terms because there is not a lot out there. I tried finding the Column using the name string in a LINQ.

```
                var Column = DBobj
                            .Where(e == name)                    
                            .Select(e)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                DBobj.Column = NewValue;
                db.Entry(DBobj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Any suggestions or documentation from the community would be very helpful.

Comment: You should show the bigger picture. Why do you want to apply these per-property updates? Where do the update instructions come from an in which form?

Comment: I'm using x editable js to do in-line edits of data in a razer view.

Comment: I don't see how that brings you to updating individual properties by name. I even think you're making this way too complicated.

Comment: That's the only way to do it.... right? https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

Comment: I can't imagine that any self-respecting javascript library forces you to update individual entity properties by name server-side. I'm not gonna read all that documentation but you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: "I'm not gonna read all that documentation but you must be doing something wrong" hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            var DBobj = db.AccountsConfigDatas.Find(0);
            var propertyInfo = DBobj.GetType().GetProperty(name); 
            propertyInfo.SetValue(DBobj, NewValue);                
            db.Entry(DBobj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Documentation:[Type.GetProperty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Don't set `db.Entry(DBobj).State = EntityState.Modified`. EF already knows a property was modified.

Comment: @Gert advice taken. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [X-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html) forces you to update properties by name. In my opinion your architecture shouldn't allow idiosyncrasies of a UI library to bleed into the deeper regions of your application code. An abstraction/mapping layer between controllers and DAL (or services) is recommended.

Anyway, as long as you don't have that, with Entity Framework it's easy to modify properties by name. No reflection required because EF has cached the meta data of the entity model:

```
var dbObj = db.AccountsConfigDatas.Find(id);
db.Entry(dbObj).CurrentValues[propertyName] = newValue;
db.SaveChanges();
```

This updates one property by name and marks this single property as modified, so only this property will be in the update statement. It's bad practice to set the entity's state as modified because that generates an update statement containing all of its properties.